# How to filter object with array

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, database, json

I want to filter this object with array aaData that will show only unique values for example if 1st have name testowy2 and 2nd and 3rd have testowy that should shows only one testowy data.

```
var json_data =
    {
        "sEcho": 1,
        "iTotalRecords": 54,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords": 54,
        "aaData": [
            [
                "79",
                "testowy2",
                "testowy samochod",
                "12.00",
                "14.00",
                "2147483647",
                "posciel",
                ""
            ],
            [
                "81",
                "testowy",
                "testowy produkt",
                "12.00",
                "14.00",
                "2147483647",
                "posciel",
                ""
            ],
            [
                "82",
                "testowy",
                "testowy produkt",
                "12.00",
                "14.00",
                "2147483647",
                "posciel",
                ""
            ]
        ]
    };
```

I tried in this way but it wont work

```
var list = "";
var parser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_data));
console.log(parser);
for(var i = 0; i < parser.aaData.length; i++){  
    for(var j = 0; j < parser.aaData[i].length; j++){   
        if(parser.aaData[i][1] != list){
            $('#json').append(parser.aaData[i][j]+"<br/>");     
            list = parser.aaData[i][j];
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Which one of them is considered as the `name`?

Comment: Counting from 0, 1st value is name for example testowy2, testowy, testowy

Comment: Looks like jquery datatables, what is your programming language? Ruby, Php, Python??

Comment: I want to make it in javascript, jquery it's retunred by datatables plugin in jquery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to see unique data you could use list to collect a array of unique names.
Something like:

```
var list = [];
var parser = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json_data));
for (var i = 0; i < parser.aaData.length; i++) {
    if (list.indexOf(parser.aaData[i][1]) < 0) {
        for (var j = 0; j < parser.aaData[i].length; j++) {
            $('#json').append(parser.aaData[i][j] + "<br/>");
        }
    }
    list.push(parser.aaData[i][1]);
}
```

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ltu8E/)

Comment: @user3211948, there are many guru's here on SO :) some of them are mine also, you will find nice people around here. Not just me lol :)